# LocalDate parse stucks on HashMap.put

Tags: java, parsing, localdate

On production I see strange behavior of `LocalDate.parse` - it makes a thread stuck.
Any ideas what can cause this?

```
"SomeTimer" #152 prio=5 os_prio=0 cpu=60796787.30ms elapsed=762351.55s tid=0x00007f5f579b9000 nid=0x5131 runnable  [0x00007f5e90189000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
    at java.util.HashMap.hash(java.base@11.0.4/HashMap.java:339)
    at java.util.HashMap.put(java.base@11.0.4/HashMap.java:607)
    at java.time.format.DateTimeParseContext.setParsedField(java.base@11.0.4/DateTimeParseContext.java:365)
    at java.time.format.DateTimeFormatterBuilder$NumberPrinterParser.setValue(java.base@11.0.4/DateTimeFormatterBuilder.java:2882)
    at java.time.format.DateTimeFormatterBuilder$NumberPrinterParser.parse(java.base@11.0.4/DateTimeFormatterBuilder.java:2869)
    at java.time.format.DateTimeFormatterBuilder$CompositePrinterParser.parse(java.base@11.0.4/DateTimeFormatterBuilder.java:2370)
    at java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.parseUnresolved0(java.base@11.0.4/DateTimeFormatter.java:2107)
    at java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.parseResolved0(java.base@11.0.4/DateTimeFormatter.java:2036)
    at java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.parse(java.base@11.0.4/DateTimeFormatter.java:1948)
    at java.time.LocalDate.parse(java.base@11.0.4/LocalDate.java:428)
    at com.MyHelper$1.compare(MyHelper.java:48)
    at com.MyHelper$1.compare(MyHelper.java:45)
    at java.util.TreeMap.getEntryUsingComparator(java.base@11.0.4/TreeMap.java:374)
    at java.util.TreeMap.getEntry(java.base@11.0.4/TreeMap.java:343)
    at java.util.TreeMap.get(java.base@11.0.4/TreeMap.java:277)
    at com.google.common.collect.StandardTable.getOrCreate(StandardTable.java:134)
    at com.google.common.collect.StandardTable.put(StandardTable.java:148)
    at com.google.common.collect.TreeBasedTable.put(TreeBasedTable.java:68)
```

The code which caused this error:

```java
DateTimeFormatter TAB_INDICATOR_DATE_TIME_FORMATER = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd-MMM-yyyy", Locale.US);
            
....
TreeBasedTable<String, String, Integer> daysInfoMap = TreeBasedTable.create(new Comparator<String>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(String o1, String o2) {
        return LocalDate.parse(o2, TAB_INDICATOR_DATE_TIME_FORMATER)
            .compareTo(LocalDate.parse(o1,TAB_INDICATOR_DATE_TIME_FORMATER));
    }
}, (Comparator<String>) (o1, o2) -> 0);
    
//    ....
           
daysInfoMap.put(registrationDateStr, "newApplications", ++count);
```

Comment: Can you provide sample inputs?

Comment: registrationDateStr is string like "14-Dec-2020", "06-Jun-2021", "01-Jun-2021"

Comment: Sorry, its my fault: copied wrong format. I've fixed the question.

Comment: The given line in `hash()` is `return (key == null) ? 0 : (h = key.hashCode()) ^ (h >>> 16);` (and `key.hashCode()` would calculate the hashcode of a `TemporalField`), I don't really see how it could be stuck there. Are you sure you're looking at the right thread?

Comment: Are you using `TreeBasedTable` correctly? It's not thread-safe. "Note that this implementation is not synchronized. If multiple threads access this table concurrently and one of the threads modifies the table, it must be synchronized externally."

Comment: Can you reproduce that stacktrace reliably? Because there really isn't much in `HashMap.hash()` to be stuck in. I suspect the real reason is somewhere else.

Comment: A wild shot, what happens if you use pattern `dd-MMM-uuuu`?